# iterating over a set of pointers

Tags: c++

In my current project, I have the following type of set:

```
typedef set<ItemPtr>            ItemSet;
```

where ItemPtr is this class:

```
class ItemPtr
{
    private:
    Item    *ptr;

    public:
    ItemPtr(Item *ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }
    Item* getPtr() const { return ptr; }
};
```

And the following sets:

```
ItemSet bookList;
ItemSet movieList;
ItemSet musicAlbumList;
```

Which are all sets contained in a class called Library.  Each of these sets contain instances of ItemPtr, where each instance of ItemPtr contains a pointer to to an instance of Book, Movie, or MusicAlbum.  Each of these are derived classes from a class called Item.  An instance of Book, contains an author, title, number of Pages, and a set of keywords that are common to that book.  I have a function as such:

```
const ItemSet* Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword)
{
    return NULL;  //need to put code in here
}
```

that needs to return all items from each set that have the parameter in its list of keywords.  I am unsure how to iterate through each set, and access it's keywords, then compare them to the parameter of the above function.  How can I do such a comparison?

Here is my Item class:

```
class Item
{
    public:
    string mTitle;
    string mArtist;
    Item(const string& title, const string& artist);
    Item();
    virtual ostream &print(std::ostream &os) const
    {
        os << "author: \t" << mArtist << endl;
        os << "title: \t" << mTitle << endl;
        return os;
    }
    virtual ~Item();
    set<string>  keywordsList;
    void addKeywords(string keyword);
};
```

This is the addKeywords function:

```
void Item::addKeywords(string keyword)
{
keywordsList.insert(keyword);
}
```

And here is as far as I've gotten thus far on writing the function I need:

```
const ItemSet* Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword)
{
ItemSet temp;

for(it=bookList.begin();it!=bookList.end();it++){
    if(it->getPtr()->keywordsList)


}

return &temp;
}
```

I know that by referencing getPtr with my iterator, it gives me access to keywordsList, but from that point I don't know how to examine the list to compare it to the passed in keyword.  My plan is to, after comparing and finding a match, store the instance in temp, then pass back temp with all the items that contained that keyword. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: Well I understand how to use a for loop to iterate through the set, but for each instance I iterate over, I am unsure how to do a comparison of that instances list of keywords, to the keyword parameter.

Comment: To compare the instance's list of keywords, start by iterating through the list of keywords.

Comment: well, you havent provided any of the code to do with `Item` which I guess is where the keywords are stored. Additionally u should just use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `ItemPtr`. A far as checking for keywords, its just checking keyword against each of the list of keywords..

Answer (score 1):

In terms of simply iterating, there are several ways to do it:

Before C++11:

```
const ItemSet* item_set = // ...
for (ItemSet::const_iterator it = item_set->begin(); it != item_set->end(); ++it) {
   const ItemPtr item = *it;
   // ...
}
```

After C++11 (using auto):

```
const ItemSet* item_set = // ...
for (auto it = item_set->cbegin(); it != item_set->cend(); ++it) {
  const ItemPtr item = *it;
}
```

After C++11 (using ranged-for):

```
const ItemSet* item_set = // ...
for (auto item : *item_set) {
   // ...
}
```

As far as processing each item, you'll need to show us the code for Item as well as some of your own attempts, first.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::set::find to check whether the keyword is present in the set
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/

Note: all over your post you are talking about finding the keyword in list. It's not a list that you are using. You are using a set.

Comment: Sorry, I am saying list because my set is called keywordsList.  I understand that yes I can use find, but the parameter is _kty, which in my case refers to ItemPtr.  I am unsure how to use that type of paramater to access keywordsList, and begin comparing.

Comment: Is this what you want
it->getPtr()->keywordsList.find(keyword)

Comment: yes, but then how would I either: A) compare it to the parameter, then add that instance into my temporary ItemSet, or B) store that instance into the temporary ItemSet if it is true that it contains that keyword?  Thanks for the help btw

Comment: the find mentioned above returns an iterator. Check if the iterator is null. If it is null, your keyword is not present in the set. If it is not null, it is present. Just dereference the iterator and add it to your temporary ItemSet.

Comment: Still not sure how to do the check.  I executed that line and stepped through it with the debugger, and it doesn't show a null iterator.  It shows it is still pointing to that instance.  How would you perform the check?  That line of code can't simply be compared to NULL